# Resizing image after drop

Tags: jquery

From this [code](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/07/drag-and-drop-jquery-with-clone-remove.html) how can I drop the same image size at the same time resize the image after drop. I tried this `drag and drop` in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErL5H/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u drag and drop the helper.clone - x is the element of droped element u can set any css to it ..

```
  //this x is ur dragged element add any css to it .. 
            x.css("height", "50px");
            x.css("width", "50px");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ErL5H/3/)